# WP8 Background Agent - Code executes fine outside of agent, fails inside?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, background-agents

I have a background agent I created to update my live tile. The agent schedules and executes fine, but the code that the agent executes has became the problem - it simply fails to execute fully and provides no error. From what I can tell, there are no restricted APIs that I am using, unless the Cimbalino toolkit is somehow providing a problem, even though I am using the background-agent-specific version from NuGet.

Code appears to stop executing when RenderText() and RenderTextWide() fail to run. No error is provided. The same code works perfectly fine when run in the foreground app.

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using Microsoft.Phone.Scheduler;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using Microsoft.Phone.Info;
using Cimbalino.Phone.Toolkit;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;
using Cimbalino.Phone.Toolkit.Extensions;

namespace ScheduledTaskAgent1
{
    public class ScheduledAgent : ScheduledTaskAgent
    {
        private static volatile bool _classInitialized;

        public ScheduledAgent()
        {
            if (!_classInitialized)
            {
                _classInitialized = true;
                // Subscribe to the managed exception handler
                Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate
                {
                    Application.Current.UnhandledException += ScheduledAgent_UnhandledException;
                });
            }
        }

        /// Code to execute on Unhandled Exceptions
        private void ScheduledAgent_UnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            }
        }

        //Method to create normal tile image
        private static void RenderText(string currproperty)
        {
            WriteableBitmap b = new WriteableBitmap(336, 336);
            var canvas = new Grid();
            canvas.Width = b.PixelWidth;
            canvas.Height = b.PixelHeight;
            var background = new Canvas();
            background.Height = b.PixelHeight;
            background.Width = b.PixelWidth;

            SolidColorBrush backColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
            background.Background = backColor;

            TextBlock currtemp = new TextBlock();
            currtemp.FontSize = 100;
            currtemp.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Segoe UI Light");
            currtemp.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
            currtemp.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
            currtemp.Text = currproperty;
            currtemp.Margin = new Thickness(20, 10, 0, 0);
            currtemp.Width = b.PixelWidth - currtemp.Margin.Left * 2;
            canvas.Children.Add(currtemp);

            b.Render(background, null);
            b.Render(canvas, null);
            b.Invalidate();
            using (IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream imageStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("/Shared/ShellContent/BackBackgroundImage2.png", System.IO.FileMode.Create, isf))
                {

                    b.SavePng(imageStream);
                }
            }
        }

        //Method to create wide tile image
        private static void RenderTextWide(string currproperty)
        {
            WriteableBitmap b = new WriteableBitmap(691, 336);
            var canvas = new Grid();
            canvas.Width = b.PixelWidth;
            canvas.Height = b.PixelHeight;
            var background = new Canvas();
            background.Height = b.PixelHeight;
            background.Width = b.PixelWidth;

            //Created background color as Accent color
            SolidColorBrush backColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
            background.Background = backColor;

            TextBlock currtemp = new TextBlock();
            currtemp.FontSize = 100;
            currtemp.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Segoe UI Light");
            currtemp.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
            currtemp.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
            currtemp.Text = currproperty;
            currtemp.Margin = new Thickness(20, 10, 0, 0);
            currtemp.Width = b.PixelWidth - currtemp.Margin.Left * 2;
            canvas.Children.Add(currtemp);

            using (IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream imageStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("/Shared/ShellContent/WideBackBackgroundImage2.png", System.IO.FileMode.Create, isf))
                {
                    b.SavePng(imageStream);
                }
            }
        }

        //When task invokes, run the tile update code.
        protected override void OnInvoke(ScheduledTask task)
        {
            ShellTile tile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.FirstOrDefault();
            if (tile != null)
            {
                FlipTileData flipTile = new FlipTileData();
                flipTile.Title = "";
                flipTile.BackTitle = "Atmosphere";
                RenderText("Test");
                RenderTextWide("Test");
                flipTile.BackBackgroundImage = new Uri("/Assets/NewUI/1.PNG", UriKind.Relative); //Default image for Background Image Medium Tile 336x336 px
                flipTile.BackgroundImage = new Uri(@"isostore:/Shared/ShellContent/BackBackgroundImage2.png", UriKind.Absolute); //Generated image for Back Background 336x336

                flipTile.WideBackBackgroundImage = new Uri("/Assets/NewUI/2.PNG", UriKind.Relative); ////Default image for Background Image Wide Tile 691x336 px
                flipTile.WideBackgroundImage = new Uri(@"isostore:/Shared/ShellContent/WideBackBackgroundImage2.png", UriKind.Absolute);
                tile.Update(flipTile);

                //Tile updated, tell agent operation complete
                NotifyComplete();
            }
        }      
    }
}
```

Comment: Surely you have visited here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202942(v=vs.105).aspx and here http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Background_Agents_Debugging_Tips_on_Windows_Phone

Comment: Yes I have, and don't see anything that could prevent it from running other then the memory cap, which I have no way of knowing about. I'll look into the logging method also

Comment: Change to ResourseIntensiveTask maybe?

Comment: @MikkoViitala Did you read everything on the first link that you've given and especially the part about ResourseIntensiveTask? It may never run! It is completely unreliable and should not be used for anything important! I highly doubt that's what Kevin wants...

Comment: @Kevin Have you tried the background task with the debugger attached? I don't think the constraints are applied in this case, so you'll see if it works without them. You can force start the background task using [ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.scheduler.scheduledactionservice.launchfortest). Also, you can get how much memory the task is using with [DeviceStatus.ApplicationPeakMemoryUsage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.info.devicestatus.applicationpeakmemoryusage).

Comment: Agents won't run while debugging, maybe logging is the best choice.

Comment: @MikkoViitala What do you mean "won't run"?

Answer (score 3):

I just ran the code that you shared in a background agent with debugger attached, and the problem was quite obvious - it throws an exception! An invalid cross-thread access exception to be precise. All UI-related work must happen int the UI thread and instantiating controls and WriteableBitmaps is such work.

**Solution**

You need to use `Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` to invoke `RenderText` and `RenderTextWide` in the appropriate thread. You can also just invoke everything in `OnInvoke` in the UI thread.

*Note:* `Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` invokes the given action asynchronously, so if you don't run everything on the UI thread, you may need to do something to sync the different threads.

**NotifyComplete**

You must ALWAYS call `NotifyComplete` AFTER you've done all the work. Basically what you need to do is try-catch(all) and then call `NotifyComplete`. Also, you may want to put it in `ScheduledAgent_UnhandledException` just in case.

`NotifyComplete` shouldn't be in an `if` as in your code, although that condition is always true in Windows Phone. `ShellTile.ActiveTiles` always has at least one tile - the primary tile - even if it's not pinned.

**Debugging background agents**

Yes, you can do that. If the agent is not working, the best way to see what's the problem is to launch the app with the debugger attached, force the background agent's invocation and put a breakpoint in the code that you want to check. Use [`ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.scheduler.scheduledactionservice.launchfortest) to start the background agent sooner than normal.

**Offtopic/Questions**

May I ask what are you trying to achieve with that `private static volatile bool _classInitialized` field? And why is it `volatile`?

Answer (score 2):

I also have seen this problem with my application after upgrading from WP8.0 to WP8.1 Silverlight.  My scheduled agent "crashes" absolutely silently at arbitrary points in my code (generating live tiles).  The crashes or hangs occur frequently and no exceptions are thrown.  I've been working on this on and off for over a month now with no success.  I've been very side-tracked thinking I was causing the problem myself somehow.  I did find a reference last night that may be the solution.  I haven't fully tested it yet in my application.

In the WP8.1 Silverlight API change notes there is a very cryptic paragraph that says:

> For a managed Windows Phone 8 ScheduledTaskAgent to be able to access
>   Silverlight 8.1 features, it runs on the modern execution stack, which
>   is converged with Windows. This uses a different CPU quota mechanism
>   than Windows Phone 8. In some cases, a Silverlight 8.1 background
>   agent might find that it gets less CPU time than it did previously. If
>   that happens, the app may choose to call RequestAccessAsync(). This
>   will increase the CPU quota given to the agent.

I've found some posts [elsewhere](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/cecf5c58-5402-4d91-a093-f7ca449f1a84/background-tasks-and-requestaccessasync?forum=wpdevelop)  indicating that the following code fixes the problem for some when placed immediately before adding a background agent task:

```
await Windows.ApplicationModel.Background.BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();
```

I would love to hear if others are seeing these types of problems and if this helps them.

Comment: It worked for me. Wasted at least 4 days behind this. Background task use to crash, no try catch fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!.

I have the same problem and I solved with the following code:

Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate() { RenderText("Test"); });
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate() { RenderTextWide("Test"); });

The file ScheduledAgent.cs:

```
    protected override void OnInvoke(ScheduledTask task)
    {
        ShellTile tile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.FirstOrDefault();
        if (tile != null)
        {
            FlipTileData flipTile = new FlipTileData();
            flipTile.Title = "";
            flipTile.BackTitle = "Atmosphere";

            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate() { RenderText("Test"); });
            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate() { RenderTextWide("Test"); });

            flipTile.BackBackgroundImage = new Uri("/Assets/NewUI/1.PNG", UriKind.Relative); //Default image for Background Image Medium Tile 336x336 px
            flipTile.BackgroundImage = new Uri(@"isostore:/Shared/ShellContent/BackBackgroundImage2.png", UriKind.Absolute); //Generated image for Back Background 336x336

            flipTile.WideBackBackgroundImage = new Uri("/Assets/NewUI/2.PNG", UriKind.Relative); ////Default image for Background Image Wide Tile 691x336 px
            flipTile.WideBackgroundImage = new Uri(@"isostore:/Shared/ShellContent/WideBackBackgroundImage2.png", UriKind.Absolute);
            tile.Update(flipTile);

            //Tile updated, tell agent operation complete
            NotifyComplete();
        }
    }
```